# How can I store strings with variables in them in another Java class?

Tags: java, string

I would like to store a series of "Strings" in a separate class (Constants.java) for organizational purposes.

**Constants.java:**

```
public static final String qualification1 = "'Priority' = \"" + priority + "\" AND 'Status' = \"In Progress\" AND 'Assignee' = \"" + assigneeInput + "\"";
...
```

In my main application class I would like to call these from from above

**Main.java:**

```
// Examples to show that these variables are dynamic
String assigneeInput = soapResponseAssignee.getSOAPBody().getTextContent();
String[] priorityList = {"Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"};

for (String priority : priorityList) {
    String qualification = RemedyConstants.qualification1;
    String qualification = RemedyConstants.qualification2;
    String qualification = RemedyConstants.qualification3;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the Strings provided to my Main class tend to have variables in them, i.e. `priority` or `assigneeInput`, which are defined there. If I store the strings elsewhere, i.e. Constants.java, I will not actually be using the Strings that I want. How can I provide the strings that I want while referencing those variables in their appropriate context?

Comment: Step 1) learn about `Properties` files. Step 2 create a `.properties` file. Step 3) store strings in the `.properties` file using `{0}...{n}` placeholders. Step 4) create a utility class (like your `Constants`) that has a `getString(String key, Object... arguments)`. Step 5) implement the method using `Properties` and `MessageFormat.format`. Step 6) Add a caching layer for the `MessageFormat` instances if required. Step 7) profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String format

```
public static final String qualification1 = "'Priority' = \"%s\" AND 'Status' = \"In Progress\" AND 'Assignee' = \"%s\"";
```

Then when you want to use it

```
String.format(qualification1, "Low", "Alice");
```

Or add function into your class doing the format

```
String getQualification1(String priority, String assignee) {
    return String.format(qualification1, priority, assignee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. Not sure why it didn't click initially that I could treat the string as an object attribute...

**Main.java:**

```
String qualification = RemedyConstants.getQualification1(priority, assigneeInput);
```

**Constants.java:**

```
public static String getQualification1(String priority, String assigneeInput) {
        return "'Priority' = \"" + priority + "\" AND 'Status' = \"In Progress\" AND 'Assignee' = \"" + assigneeInput + "\"";
    }
```

Comment: You could do that, which will work. But hardcoding these kinds of strings into your code is bad. Also this will be somewhat slower than a cached `MessageFormat`. I would suggest that you look at [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085702/how-can-i-store-strings-with-variables-in-them-in-another-java-class#comment75193817_44085702) in more detail.